# Views and QuickTabs Layout

Tags: views, blocks

I have a view that filters based on classes (ie., 2015, 2016, 2017, etc).  I want to use QuickTabs to create a tab for each class. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Views Better Exposed Filters did the trick. :)